# Determining Image presence and absence that has certain style - Paperclip rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, paperclip

Is there a way to determine the existence of a given image style?

For example to determine whether the image exists at all, we can do:

```
    <% if @user.avatar.exists? %>
      <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:large), :id => "cropbox" %>
```

But how can we determine whether the image exists in a particular style, say for instance `thumb`?. The above condition only determines the existence of an image in its `original` style.

Comment: are you asking how to change the styles/sizes of a photo using paperclip?

Comment: No, I am asking about how to know that the certain image with certain style exists or not for a particular user.

Comment: have you tried if @user.avatar

Comment: sorry i will expand, see answer

Comment: You should use a helper method instead of putting that conditional logic into your ERB template. @alex-peattie answered the question correctly below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<% if @user.avatar(params[:large]) %><%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:large), :id => "cropbox" %><% end %>
```

Comment: `if @user.avatar` is checking the which styled image? Original, Large or Thumb.

Comment: well my interpretation is that it will check for any image, however i have just realised you want to check for a specific size dont you? sorry for the confusiuon, i have edited my answer on what i would try

Answer (score 32):

The `.exists?` function optionally takes a style_name:

```
<% if @user.avatar.exists?(:large) %>
```

should work.

Comment: Just a note this actually checks for the existence of the file. i.e. if you store your files in S3, there will be S3 call on the server, which slows down view rendering quite a bit, especially if you have multiple images on the page using this code.

Comment: Given how I read the question, this should be the accepted answer.